# Why does upsert result in a deadlock?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, locking, deadlock, upsert

I'm doing the below upsert statement, which I need to have run multiple times in a short timeframe. I wrote this statement based on examples from Aaron Bertrand's [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) post on SQLPerformance.com. The majority of my UPSERTS are INSERTS, so I used that example from his post.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT AggregationMeasurement (ValueFloat, Date, AggregationConfigurationId)
SELECT @ValueFloat, @Date, @AggregationConfigurationId
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.AggregationMeasurement WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE Date = @Date AND AggregationConfigurationId = @AggregationConfigurationId
);

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
UPDATE AggregationMeasurement SET 
    ValueFloat = @ValueFloat
WHERE Date = @Date AND AggregationConfigurationId = @AggregationConfigurationId;
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

However, every time this results in several deadlocks, as shown here:

```
<deadlock>
    <victim-list>
        <victimProcess id="process15af9222ca8" />
    </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process id="process15af9222ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 5:738101670:1 " waittime="3826" ownerId="346683" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-12-21T05:03:14.247" XDES="0x15b02ce8428" lockMode="X" schedulerid="1" kpid="92924" status="suspended" spid="127" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-21T05:03:14.070" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-21T05:03:14.030" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.030" clientapp="AzureDataMovement" hostname="ab925934100003P" hostpid="3152" loginname="YVeZ1R096I" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="346683" currentdb="5" currentdbname="b2c01-sqldb-adaptin-p-001" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="b2b213bd-1c82-4160-8b95-053eff29a124.dbo.sp_UpsertAggregateMeasurement" queryhash="0x72dd67a03d17633c" queryplanhash="0xa6cb7ceab670b343" line="9" stmtstart="348" stmtend="1026" sqlhandle="0x03000500e40bdd577809dd0091ad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    INSERT AggregationMeasurement (ValueFloat, Date, AggregationConfigurationId)
                    SELECT @ValueFloat, @Date, @AggregationConfigurationId
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS
                    (
                    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.AggregationMeasurement WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
                    WHERE Date = @Date AND AggregationConfigurationId = @AggregationConfigurationId
                </frame>
                <frame procname="b2b213bd-1c82-4160-8b95-053eff29a124.dbo.sp_AggregateMeasurement" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="136" stmtstart="10194" stmtend="10476" sqlhandle="0x0300050001c1a15c8f175c01a3ad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    EXEC sp_UpsertAggregateMeasurement @ValueFloat = @ValueFloat_tmp, @Date = @Date_tmp, @AggregationConfigurationId = @AggregationConfigurationI
                </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
                Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1554104577]
            </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process15ab49c9848" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 5:738101670:0 " waittime="3830" ownerId="346672" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-12-21T05:03:14.070" XDES="0x15afb548428" lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="49096" status="suspended" spid="121" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-21T05:03:13.927" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-21T05:03:13.857" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.857" clientapp="AzureDataMovement" hostname="adf46566100003T" hostpid="5608" loginname="YVeZ1R096I" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="346672" currentdb="5" currentdbname="b2c01-sqldb-adaptin-p-001" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="b2b213bd-1c82-4160-8b95-053eff29a124.dbo.sp_UpsertAggregateMeasurement" queryhash="0x72dd67a03d17633c" queryplanhash="0xa6cb7ceab670b343" line="9" stmtstart="348" stmtend="1026" sqlhandle="0x03000500e40bdd577809dd0091ad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    INSERT AggregationMeasurement (ValueFloat, Date, AggregationConfigurationId)
                    SELECT @ValueFloat, @Date, @AggregationConfigurationId
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS
                    (
                    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.AggregationMeasurement WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
                    WHERE Date = @Date AND AggregationConfigurationId = @AggregationConfigurationId
                </frame>
                <frame procname="b2b213bd-1c82-4160-8b95-053eff29a124.dbo.sp_AggregateMeasurement" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="136" stmtstart="10194" stmtend="10476" sqlhandle="0x0300050001c1a15c8f175c01a3ad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    EXEC sp_UpsertAggregateMeasurement @ValueFloat = @ValueFloat_tmp, @Date = @Date_tmp, @AggregationConfigurationId = @AggregationConfigurationI
                </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
                Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1554104577]
            </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <objectlock lockPartition="1" objid="738101670" subresource="FULL" dbid="5" objectname="b2b213bd-1c82-4160-8b95-053eff29a124.dbo.AggregationMeasurement" id="lock15af4c94f00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="738101670">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process15ab49c9848" mode="IX" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process15af9222ca8" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
            </waiter-list>
        </objectlock>
        <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="738101670" subresource="FULL" dbid="5" objectname="b2b213bd-1c82-4160-8b95-053eff29a124.dbo.AggregationMeasurement" id="lock15af4cc4780" mode="X" associatedObjectId="738101670">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process15af9222ca8" mode="X" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process15ab49c9848" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
            </waiter-list>
        </objectlock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

I don't get why this happens. Shouldn't `UPDLOCK` and `SERIALIZABLE` prevent these deadlocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To prevent deadlocks, you are going to want the right index on this table.**

I suggest one of the following *clustered* indexes, if you can make it unique, even better.

```sql
(Date, AggregationConfigurationId)
-- alternatively
(AggregationConfigurationId, Date)
```

---

The reason you need indexing is two-fold: otherwise the `INSERT` and `NOT EXISTS` will lock far too much, and more importantly, to force the lookups to be sequential

Picture what the server has to do. It needs to first find out if any row exists:

```sql
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.AggregationMeasurement WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE Date = @Date AND AggregationConfigurationId = @AggregationConfigurationId
)
```

If there is no (or poor) indexing, it will do a full scan of the table to find this row. And given that you've asked for `UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE`, it needs to place a `RangeS-U`-lock on any rows which it thinks could *possibly* match, and hold that until the end of the trnasaction. If that means the whole table then you get a `U`-lock on the whole table, along with an `IX` lock as well due to possible lock escalation (that appears to have happened here against a partition).

A `U` lock normally prevents a deadlock caused by reading data which may be later modified. But the fact you have a `U` lock may not help you if the `U`-locks themselves happen in the wrong order. This often happens when a query goes parallel, or when an unordered scan happens.

Whereas if you have proper indexing, the server can recognize that few (or a unique) rows will match, and therefore do a serial, ordered lookup for it. The `U` lock now works exactly as intended, preventing a deadlock by locking everything in the correct order.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you want to do is make sure you have an index that meets the needs of your WHERE clause. In this case, it would need key columns on `Date` and `AggregationConfigurationId`. Doing this will ensure the locks are held for as brief a period as possible.

After that, if your UPSERT is predominately going to be UPDATES instead of INSERTS, you'd want revise your UPSERT statement to the below statement. Otherwise, the statement you are using looks good.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE AggregationMeasurement WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
SET ValueFloat = @ValueFloat
WHERE Date = @Date
    AND AggregationConfigurationId = @AggregationConfigurationId;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT AggregationMeasurement
        (ValueFloat, Date, AggregationConfigurationId)
    VALUES (@ValueFloat, @Date, @AggregationConfigurationId)
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```